# Grouping sites into categories with Piwiki

Tags: php, web-analytics, matomo

I am using a single Piwik instance to monitor my websites.
Some of my sites are sharing the same topic, so I would like to put them into groups.

Do you know if it is possible to put websites into groups/categories when using Pwiki analytics?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a feature currently available, but might be something considered for the future. You can submit a feature request at Piwik: http://forum.piwik.org/list.php?3